# Unable to dynamically change image displayed using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery and php, so I apologize if the question is to simple.
I have to change the image displayed depending on the option selected in the list box.
So far my jquery is able to retrieve and display the desired img id.I intially tried  to post the image id back to the php script and then retrieve the image, but later realised I can directly manipulate the img tag(since my images are name 1.jpg,2.jpg).Can someone please help me? Thank you!
Here s the relevant code:

```
HTML:
<img id="design"  class ="img-rounded" alt="Ad Picture" width="450p" height="450"/>
<input type="button" id="GetImage" class="btn" value="Get Image">
Jquery:
$('#GetImage').live("click",function() {
var imageid= $('#UserIds').val();
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'ProvidingFeedback.php',
    data:{id:imageid},
    success: function(msg){ 
       if(result=='success') {
            $('#design').attr('src','/img/2.jpg');

       }
 }
});


});
```

I

Comment: What happen after the ajax post? Did you try to debug it in JS console or firebug? Are you sure the ajax is successful?

Comment: Yes the Ajax post was successful.Used an alert box to display success and checked in Firebug.

Comment: Where are you getting `result` from, there is no variable with that name, and why would you need to check if the ajax call was successful inside the `success` callback, which is only fired if the ajax call was successful? Remove the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are selecting image as id try only img or #design

```
 $('#img').attr('src','/img/2.jpg');
```

should be

```
 $('#design').attr('src','/img/2.jpg');
```

and

```
  if(msg=='success') {
```

should be

```
  if(msg=='success') {
```

Comment: I am sorry, I was just playing around with the code..i had changed the id in between.It does not work with #design either :(

Comment: try `<img id="design"  src="" class ="img-rounded" alt="Ad Picture" width="450p" height="450"/>`  put src here than change

Comment: also make sure that you are echoing only `success` on success in `ProvidingFeedback.php`

Comment: Hi all, thank you so much..I got it. The issue was the if condition in the success part. The code is working ok now.However, If anyone can answer, why was the result==success causing issue?

Comment: have you check that what are you getting in success like `alert(msg)`...  `result=='success'` which is wrong you need to check msg instead result since you are getting the mag in return not result

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'ProvidingFeedback.php',
  data:{id:imageid},
  success: function(msg){ 
   //if(result=='success') { // 'result' is not define in you code above should be 'msg'
        $('#design').attr('src','/img/2.jpg');

   //}
 }
```

If you want to get the result using `msg`

To better help you debug you code you may want to take a look @ [Chrome Developer Tools: Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints) or [Firebug Breakpoints](http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html)